# Mouse backwards button going to beginning

Tags: windows-10, mouse, mouse-buttons

I had Logitech MX Anywhere 2 for few years now, and I recently factory reset my PC. For some reason, when I press backwards button, it takes me to beginning (in win explorer to "main" page, in G.Chrome to "New Page"). Before the reset it was working perfectly. I have all drivers and software installed. The backwards function is set in the software.

Can somebody help me with this?

Comment: hi, which software did you install to change the function?  On the Mac, enabling of the back/forward buttons requires installation of Logitech Options software.

Comment: I already fixed the problem. I just repaired the device.